# Checking sp_send_email permission before executing

Tags: sql-server, email

In my stored procedure, I send emails with sp_send_email. My stored procedure will be run in different environments; some will have emailing enabled, some won't.

If I run sp_send_email without it being enabled, I (quite rightly) get this error message

> SQL Server blocked access to procedure 'dbo.sp_send_dbmail' of component 'Database Mail XPs' because this component is turned off as part of the security configuration for this server.

I want to check whether emailing is enabled first, so I can avoid the error by doing the following:

```
IF @is_enabled
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_send_email ...
END
```

How do I correctly set @is_enabled?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can query [sys.configurations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188345(SQL.90).aspx)

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT *
       FROM sys.configurations
       WHERE name = 'Database Mail XPs' AND value_in_use = 1)
    PRINT 'enabled'
ELSE
    PRINT 'no luck'
```

The downside is that it may not be visible to non-sysadmin users because of ["MetaData Visibility"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187113.aspx)

Comment: +1 yes, actually sys.configurations is better than sp_configure output

Comment: BTW the sysadmin issue can be addressed by code signing the check.

Comment: Or off-load to a start-up procedure, that sets a flag in a user table in a user database. The code signing idea is useful though.

Comment: sys.configurations actually is visible to the public role so it shouldn't require anything special under normal conditions.

Comment: This solution was perfect for me to use in dev where email is not configured.  But will work as is in prod.

Answer (score 0):

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Database Mail XPs';
GO
```

The `sp_send_mail` falls under the '[Database Mail XPs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191189.aspx)' umbrella. You application may not have the rights to run `sp_configure` and `RECONFIGURE`, so in the end you may be better if you simply try to invoke the `sp_send_mail` and handle the error.

Answer (score -1):

BOL says:

To send Database mail, users must be a user in the msdb database and a member of the DatabaseMailUserRole database role in the msdb database. To add msdb users or groups to this role use SQL Server Management Studio or execute the following statement for the user or role that needs to send Database Mail.

So, you can give to user the appropriate role:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_addrolemember @rolename = 'DatabaseMailUserRole'
    ,@membername = '<user or role name>'; GO
```

Comment: That's not what I asked. I want to check if it is enabled, and only attempt to send if it is. I don't need to know how to set it up, as it will be done already on the relevant servers.

Comment: but it is the first part of the solution.
using SELECT CURRENT_USER you can get current user name, and then check the role of this user using sp_helpuser. If he has role DatabaseMailUserRole - this user can send emails.

Comment: @Alex_L: this is not an answer to the question at all.